# Hive deletes already existing partitions

Tags: hive

I am using HIVE to load data into different partitions.

I am creating a table

```
CREATE TABLE X IF NOT EXISTS ... USING PARQUET PARTITIONED BY (Year, Month,Day)
LOCATION '...'
```

Afterwards I am performing a full load:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE ... PARTITION (Year, Month, Day)
SELECT ... FROM Y
```

Show partitions shows me all partitions correctly.

and after the full load, I just want to reload always the current year dynamically:

```
INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE ... PARTITION (Year, Month, Day)
SELECT ... FROM Y WHERE Year = YEAR(CURRENT_DATE())
```

> The issue I have is that HIVE deletes all PREVIOUS partitions i.e. 2017, 2018 and just 2019 persists. I was supposed that HIVE ONLY overwrites the partition for 2019 but not all.

I suppose I do something wrong - any idea is welcome.

Comment: Is table X an external table or internal table?

Answer (score 0):

Try using "Insert into table" instead of "Insert overwrite table". It should solve your problem. :)

Comment: Unfortunately, this leads to doubles entries.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I got the solution once I studied the official databricks guide more carefully.

Here is the answer:

The semantics are different based on the type of the target table.

Hive SerDe tables: INSERT OVERWRITE doesn’t delete partitions ahead, and only overwrite those partitions that have data written into it at runtime. This matches Apache Hive semantics. For Hive SerDe tables, Spark SQL respects the Hive-related configuration, including hive.exec.dynamic.partition and hive.exec.dynamic.partition.mode.
Native data source tables: INSERT OVERWRITE first deletes all the partitions that match the partition specification (e.g., PARTITION(a=1, b)) and then inserts all the remaining values. Since Databricks Runtime 3.2, the behavior of native data source tables can be changed to be consistent with Hive SerDe tables by changing the session-specific configuration spark.sql.sources.partitionOverwriteMode to DYNAMIC. The default mode is STATIC.